# javascript: Update property value in Array() with index as parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

Currently I've a react function that removes from a Array called rents the current rent perfect. The issue is that I need to update the rent row value called status and set property from 1 to 4 the code below works. I don't seem to get how to get the Index of rent to be able to update it.

```
removeItem (itemIndex) {
    this.state.rents.splice(itemIndex, 1) // removes the element
    this.setState({rents: this.state.rents}) // sets again the array without the value to the rent prop
    console.log(itemIndex) // itemIndex
}
```

currently I'm adding this to the code to debug but get this error

```
console.log(this.state.rents[itemIndex].unique_key)
```

Stack Trace

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'unique_key' of undefined
```

I need to be able to update the rent property value called status from 1 to 4 and **setState** again

Comment: use the set state api that takes a callback function

Comment: I really don't understand what you want to do, but if we talk about the code you posted, don't do it. Don't mutate your state like that.

Comment: @devserkan have any tutorial example so I could understand, thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use `splice` directly on your state, even better don't use it. Use `slice` or `.filter` to create new arrays. Don't assign your state using itself again like you do. You can find a good tutorial in @Thiago Loddi's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate the comments, starting first with the most important:

Like @devserkan said, you should never mutate your state (and props), otherwise you start to see some really weird hard-to-make-sense bugs. When manipulating state, always create a copy of it. You can read more [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/handling-state-in-react-four-immutable-approaches-to-consider-d1f5c00249d5).

Now for your question:

this.setState is asynchronous, so to get your state's updated value you should use a callback function

```
const rents = [...this.state.rents]; // create a copy
rents.splice(itemIndex, 1);
this.setState({ rents }, () => {
  console.log(this.state.rents); // this will be up-to-date
});
console.log(this.state.rents); // this won't
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like using the `filter` method to remove items from the state and want to give an alternative solution. As we tried to explain in the comments and @Thiago Loddi's answer, you shouldn't mutate your state like this.

For arrays, use methods like `map`, `filter`, `slice`, `concat` to create new ones according to the situation. You can also use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to shallow copy your array. Then set your state using this new one. For objects, you can use `Object.assign` or spread syntax again to create new ones.

A warning, spread syntax and `Object.assign` creates shallow copies. If you mutate a nested property of this newly created object, you will mutate the original one. Just keep in mind, for this situation you need a deep copy or you should change the object again without mutating it somehow.

Here is the alternative solution with `filter`.

```
removeItem = itemIndex => {
  const newRents = this.state.rents.filter((_, index) => index !== itemIndex);
  this.setState({ rents: newRents });
};
```

If you want to log this new state, you can use a callback to `setState` but personally, I like to log the state in the `render` method. So here is one more alternative :)

```
render() {
    console.log( this.state.rents );
    ...
}
```